# My Python script (to crop the mouth from a face) with Haarcascades and OpenCV throws the following error when run in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS terminal

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opencl, haar-classifier

This here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

mouth_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml')
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('./haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

if mouth_cascade.empty():
  raise IOError('Unable to load the mouth cascade classifier xml file')

img = cv2.imread('/home/victor/Vic.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.5,12)
for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+h]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+h]
        mouth = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray,2.0,25)
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in mouth:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (ex,ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh),(0,255,0),3)
        crop_img = img[ey:ey+eh, ex:ex+ew]
        cv2.imshow('Cropped mouth', crop_img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is what I run in the terminal and the message I get as the output respectively:

python MouthDetection.py

[ INFO:0 ] Initialize OpenCL runtime...

However, what I want is an image to pop up displaying the mouth that has been cropped from the face. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

P.S I checked that all the paths are correct and all the libraries have been installed correctly. The PYTHONPATH variable is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably showing but it is too fast. You need to either save to a file: `cv2.imwrite(filename, image)`; or

you run cv2.imshow inside an infinite loop:

```
while True:
 cv2.imshow('Cropped mouth', crop_img)
 k = cv2.waitKey(33)
    if k==27:    # Esc key to stop
        break
```

Comment: Neither one worked unfortunately. The output is still the [INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime... error message. I checked where the file (after using with imwrite)  with the crop_img might be using whereis, but it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you share the image?

Comment: I mean, put it in imgur or somewhere else we can download.